# How to define a type for an iterator for a const and non-const container version

Tags: c++, templates, stl

Consider this example:

```
template <typename T> struct A {
    using Iter = typename T::iterator;
    Iter iter;
    A(T& cont) {
        iter = cont.begin();
    }
    typename Iter::reference value() { return *iter; }
};

void f(std::vector<int>& v) {
    A a(v);
    a.value() = 10;
}
```

It work fine, buy if you add `const` to container type, it's no more compile!

```
int g(const std::vector<int>& v) {
    A a(v); // ERROR
    return a.value();
}
```

How to define iterator type, that will compile with const/non-const container type.
I need something like that:

```
using Iter = decltype(T::begin());
```

Comment: What are you doing with this iterator?  Are you going to modify what it points to?  If not, just use `T::const_iterator` and always get an iterator to const.

Comment: The iterator must allow modification if the container is not const

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea 1: check the type of the iterator directly.

Implementation:

```
   using Iter = decltype(std::declval<T>()::begin());
```

Idea 2: check if the type is `const` and define iterator using this knowledge.

Implementation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct A {
    using Iter = std::conditional_t<
                        std::is_same_v<std::remove_const_t<T>, T>, typename T::iterator, typename T::const_iterator
                                   >;
    Iter iter;
    A(T& cont) {
        iter = cont.begin();
    }
};

void f(const std::vector<int>& v) {
    A a(v);
}


void f1(std::vector<int>& v) {
    A a(v);
}
```

Comment: Idea 1 is not compiled by gcc 10, but idea 2 works! Thanks you!

Comment: @user3324131 sorry, there was a typo, Idea 1 is `decltype(std::declval<T>().begin());`. This should work.